# iPhone save game state

Tags: iphone, c++

I'm implementing a save game feature to my game, so I'm looking for the best way to store the saved game.

Since I'm using C++ everywhere it's possible, I can't use NSKeyedArchiver to store the state of the game.
I am thinking in saving the state manually in a file, so I have a questions about that:

In which subfolder of apphome should I save that file? Looking into the [iOS Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html) I didn't found a folder that perfeclty fit that need. Should I create a custom subfolder in Library or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @John Percival Hackworth Probably because of performance issues, Objective-C is slow for games ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the file into the Documents directory (NSDocumentDirectory). Thats the path to save your stuff, you can alter its content in any way by eg. adding subfolders for your save games or whatever.
DON'T save it inside the library folder!

Comment: For some reason I thought the Documents folder was for sharing documents with the user (which I didn't want), reading again it is clear that sharing with user is optional (and require some configuration for that). Thanks